# Termini per "addizionare" e "addizione" nel Quattrocento e nel Cinquecento

Tags: history, synonym, mathematics

Qualche mese fa, su
 [Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32974/), si è chiesta a proposito del lessico usato nel *Sumario Compendioso*, il primo libro di matematica pubblicato in America nel 1556, una domanda che personalmente ho trovato interessante. Si chiedeva sui diversi termini usati nel vocabolario dell'epoca per i concetti di "addizionare" e "addizione" e ce ne sono stati trovati parecchi. Il fatto curioso esposto nella domanda è che, in questo libro, si usa il verbo castigliano "ajustar" come sinonimo di "sumar" (cioè, "addizionare"), ma l'OP non era riuscito a trovare nessuna fonte che affermasse che tale verbo avesse avuto questo significato (ovviamente, oggi non ha questo senso). Si è scoperto che questo verbo, scritto anche nella forma "aiustar", si era usato come sinonimo di "addizionare" non soltanto in castigliano, ma anche in catalano e in occitano.

Avrei curiosità di fare una domanda analoga per la lingua italiana: quali vocaboli si erano usati per esprimere "addizionare" e "addizione" nel Quattrocento e nel Cinquecento?

Per cominciare, possiamo cercare quale verbo si usa nella *Summa de Arithmetica, Geometria, Proportioni et 
Proportionalita* di Luca Pacioli, pubblicata nel 1494, che si può sfogliare dal sito web della [Biblioteca virtual Miguel de Cervantes](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/summa-de-arithmetica-geometria-proportioni-et-proportionalita--2/html/ffa66d5e-82b1-11df-acc7-002185ce6064.htm). Se guardiamo la sezione ["Continentia de tutta lopera"](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/summa-de-arithmetica-geometria-proportioni-et-proportionalita--2/html/ffa66d5e-82b1-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_4.htm), che sarebbe più o meno come l'indice del libro, possiamo vedere che si utilizza "sumare".

Si tratta, in effetto, di una delle forme alternative di "sommare" che appaiono sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000385.jpg), adoperata anche da Tartaglia. Nei *Testi veneziani del Duecento e dei primi del Trecento* appare "somare", mentre il Seneca volgar (XIII secolo) e Nicolò Franco utilizzano "sommare". Infine, anche Galileo, nelle *Due lezioni all'Accademia fiorentina circa la figura, sito e grandezza dell'Inferno di Dante* (1588), usa "sommare".

Comment: Trovo, in una trascrizione dell'Algebra di Bombelli, “somma” e “sommare”, “sottrattione” e “sottrare” https://amslaurea.unibo.it/3682/1/fulvi_valeria_tesi.pdf

Comment: @egreg: Anche "raccogliere"?

Comment: C'è solo una occorrenza: “Lo sommare, over raccogliere di R.q. con numero non si può fare se non per via del più”, ma indica che “raccogliere” si usava.

Comment: @egreg: Ce ne sono tre: cerca "raccog". E c'è anche "raccolto".

Comment: @egreg: Comunque, il lessico che c'è all'inizio è molto divertente.

Comment: @egreg: Da [*Larte de labbacho* di Treviso](https://vec.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Larte_de_labbacho) (1478): «cinqz sono gli atti: li quali besogna sapere a chi vuol intendere la fine de questa prattica, zoe, Numerare, Iungere, Cauare, Moltiplicare, e Partire». Quindi, anche "iungere".

Comment: Nell'[*Arithmetica*](https://books.google.es/books?id=y7O2evuy1P0C&pg=PP5&lpg=PP5&dq=Arithmetica+%22Chi+d%27arte+Matematice%22&source=bl&ots=WcbA6Ujkbc&sig=ACfU3U3IalFC1mCnkwUjc-rAq3wnMx1Ejg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj__KToi8zoAhVj8-AKHT_BCcMQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=Arithmetica%20%22Chi%20d'arte%20Matematice%22&f=false) di Pietro Borghi (1484) si usa "sumar": «[...] 5 atti arithmeticali, como e numerar, multiplicar, partir, sumar, & sottrar, [...]».